# Will Setting a Reply To Address at a Different Domain Result in Spam

Tags: email, spam, transactional-email

I send transactional emails from my application on my customers behalf. I'd like for the receiver to be able to click reply and have the reply go directly to my customer, without ever touching my server.

If I send an email from me@myapp.com with the reply-to header set to customer@gmail.com will my transactional emails be flagged as spam? Is this even the slightest red flag to spam filters? It's important my emails don't get caught in the spam folder and i've spent quite a bit of time ensuring that my email is sent properly so I just want to be sure before I implement something like that. Or is this a fairly common practice that I shouldn't be concerned at all about?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was able to find the answer at another location http://www.quora.com/Does-sending-emails-with-a-From-address-with-a-different-domain-from-the-Reply-To-address-hurt-ones-deliverability

Apparently the reply-to header can be set to another domain without any threat to the deliverability of the email. On some of the smaller mail admins this may cause a problem, but technically speaking its perfectly legitimate.

Comment: I would argue that the opposite is written in the link, see "I've always been of the oppinion that a reply to address of a different domain is worse because it is trickery of sorts. but addresses using the same domain, even if it is a different sub-domain should not be a problem."

Comment: The 2 most prominent comments on that link are complete opposites: "No, that's what we (at Postmark) recommend doing to send from your customers email address. The key is to make sure you have configured SPF and DKIM authentication in place for the From email domain ... Often when delivery issues arise with Postmark customers, they are because DKIM and SPF were not configured. As the other reply here suggests, smaller email admins may react strangely to this configuration, but you can't worry too much about all the small admins; they all act incorrectly from time to time."

Comment: The other one is marked as ChatGPT content. I probably shouldn't even mention it: "Sending emails with a different domain in the From: address compared to the Reply-To: address can potentially hurt your deliverability. This is because some email providers may see it as a sign of potential spam or phishing. It's best to keep the domains consistent across both fields, as it can help establish trust and improve your chances of having your emails delivered successfully."

Answer (score 5):

Provided your sender address is properly set and matches your DKIM/SPF DNS records, you're correct that a reply-to should not negatively effect your sender reputation.

But ultimately it's a provider level decision, so YMMV across different inbox providers.